# IE Input and click

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, excel-2010, vba

Please see my script for opening IE and searching text from an Excel cell (activecell).

Problems -

- Macro does not click ok.
- Sometimes Google search field is blank
- Sometimes the IE box does not appear in front of all other running applications
- When search word is in the search field I am required to press enter manually

Tryed to add sendkeys at the end of the script but did not work.

```
Sub googlesearchactivecell()

'
' Working
'

Dim MyItem As String, IE As Object, MyElements As Object

MyItem = ActiveCell.Value

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.Navigate "www.google.com"

While IE.busy = True

Wend

Set MyElements = IE.Document.GetelementsbyTagName("Input")

For Each MyLoop In MyElements

If MyLoop.Name = "q" Then MyLoop.Value = MyItem

If MyLoop.Value = "Google Search" Then: MyLoop.Click: Exit For

Next MyLoop

IE.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Comment: use this instead: `IE.Document.GetelementsbyID("Ist-lb").Value = myItem` before the loop, then eliminate the `if MyLoop.Name = "q"` line.

Comment: Please state where and what is to be replaced. Thank you. Im unable to make sense of this.